# Data binding of CSS class attribute in XML view

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

How can I bind the value of the CSS class attribute of a XML fragment to a model property within another XML view?

The following snipped works fine

```
<core:Fragment fragmentName="com.foo.bar.Fragment" type="XML" class="important"/>
```

and should be changed to something like

```
<core:Fragment fragmentName="com.foo.bar.Fragment" type="XML" class="{itemStatus}"/>
```

where `{itemStatus}`should be bound to model property.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is indeed not possible to bind the class attribute, as Qualiture already mentioned.
However, there is a workaround using custom data, which can be bound, written to the DOM and hence also used for styling purposes. 
You can see an example here in the documentation: [Writing Data to the HTML DOM as DATA-* Attribute](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1ef9fefa2a574735957dcf52502ab8d0.html)

Hope that helps